# Default callback return type conflicts with generic type which should be inferred as that return type

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, typescript-generics, react-typescript

I am working on a React hook and I am running into an issue where I want to have part of the return type be inferred from the return type of a function passed into the hook, but I am not quite getting it working:

```js
const useFetch = <ResponseType>(
  fetchInputFactory: () => RequestInfo | URL | [RequestInfo | URL, RequestInit],
  deps: DependencyList | undefined,
  transformResponse: (response: Response) => Promise<ResponseType> = async (response) => response
):
  | { loading: true }
  | { loading: false; success: true; response: ResponseType }
  | { loading: false; success: false; error: Error }
```

The error I am getting is:

```
(parameter) response: Response
Type 'Promise<Response>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<ResponseType>'.
  Type 'Response' is not assignable to type 'ResponseType'.
    'ResponseType' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'Response'.ts(2322)
index.ts(6, 22): The expected type comes from the return type of this signature.
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, a generic type can always be *explicitly specified* by the consumer code.

Therefore, even though when the 3rd argument `transformResponse` is not provided, it defaults to an async identity function, and we would expect TypeScript to infer that `ResponseType` is just `Response`, this inference could be overridden by the consuming code:

```
const f = useFetch<number>(someFetchInputFactoryFn, []);
//    ^? { loading: true } | { loading: false; success: true; response: number } | { loading: false; success: false; error: Error }
// TS expects `response` to be a number, but it should be a `Response`...
```

Constraining the generic type is not enough, because a very bad consuming code could always explicitly specify a type that extends `Response`, but if it does not provide the corresponding `transformResponse` argument, the hook implementation cannot match that arbitrary type.

Hence we want to *prevent* the possibility to explicitly specify the generic type when `transformResponse` is not provided, so that the response type will always be `Response` in that case. But if it *is* provided, then we need the generic type (and if the consuming code still tries to explicitly pass a mismatching type, TS will yell at its `transformResponse` value, not at the hook default value).

For this situation, we can use a *function overload*, so that in one case there is *no* generics to mess with, and in the other case, the hook return type is associated with the passed `transformResponse` callback return type:

```
// A type to simplify the return expression
type HookReturn<ResponseType> =
    | { loading: true }
    | { loading: false; success: true; response: ResponseType }
    | { loading: false; success: false; error: Error }

// Note: omitting the first 2 arguments, since they do not play a role in the issue
function useFetch2(): HookReturn<Response>;
function useFetch2<ResponseType>(transformResponse: (response: Response) => Promise<ResponseType>): HookReturn<ResponseType>;
function useFetch2(transformResponse = (async (response: Response) => response)) {
    return { // Dummy implementation
        loading: true
    }
}
```

Let's check its usage:

```
// Form with no transformResponse, defaults to async identity, and return type to Response
const a = useFetch2() // Okay
//    ^? HookReturn<Response>

// Form with no transformResponse, but trying to specify a generic type
const b = useFetch2<number>() // Error: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.
//        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//    ^? HookReturn<Response>

// Form with provided transformResponse, return type is inferred from the callback return
const c = useFetch2(async () => true) // Okay
//    ^? HookReturn<boolean>

// Form with provided transformResponse, explicitly specifying a mismatching generic type
const d = useFetch2<number>(async () => true) // Error: Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'number'.
//                                      ~~~~
//    ^? HookReturn<number>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBArhApgMUVYALGBeGAeAJUQgAdwkAVATxMQBoA+ACgCgZ2YB6TgMzUwCSYEnCjIAhsCggATlQBcMJgEocDGEQCOcYlCE8QMAD4wAqgQAyxmAG0tO6PsMnzFuhsTbdQgJZQAunRsHNwAJogkEIoAIhGIYOFgwFQWPtDWcAmIPD5giKFBHDBQMuKQBjIAtkSk5IiKTDLEZJD1HrWtqtjqAAoyIJVpiITNddS06rjiEFRJSk0dSF3qCy1IXJwwAKIy-TKKAOQ1a4jjiAcwoHAANqEwAEaIMLnQZVA+4lD5MADuflhlGDiGT3PylOTFGhPH4YHyYS4gG53R7wMBNa6fb7SGBHUatA4AOhYynkwXYJgA3jBriBxKFcgBzRQlHQwAC+ZOsVJpdMZih44muSAA3DAIHBgMBiFFijIdKLVnVFMcxlD2ZzKdTafSwEyYAKhYhReLJdL+YKRTBELtZIodnt2WoYBTOU0oHAZGBnRsYNE4JVKlRnpUSNdEJV4lBPj5wJyijydXqWYhORyOSxQJBYDwcPAkKh0Bg8GB-Y8ZMxlCxuEUAHoAfhYLCgaoAEiAQABrIjuz0jRanKGTLla3m65lyp4coqahN8-UWo1iiVSiAy5MKvFIZWbge0dXT72zsfzw3G5dmk+W617O02mTqqubAByIC+igGfneuuKGCeORk6QAExAjIDL+pGEDuBAuRSj+iBBqEhhgK+MChuIQbiDA-Rhs8XpQL+zyrjoLA8JkUgxl6CAoPwGCASoihtp23YemAfYnAwwokWR7zgHm1GFoBbGqhMTAlGUEAVNUO4NIqrTbv2ywwH0H5IEJrRnAwJIwIxXZoCxamUIOnGkUkPGUfmNF0WJ5SyFJ-a5kw0yzMA8zSe0JyKbJSyqC6RRuix3rVn6AZBj4IZhhGYBRmZcYcEeSYTqmLDptWyC2b8-wwMhsriZJKqtO44QCjcUAQMUhhOXMPiJO8zbuGUdz+Z6kJ7ti+VIBm5CwJhuBUQWmB0ZW1YcPWjapelfz4VlhjWRJtntfQDyiLKVCMuVYq0MAPg8BhMAMvE1pwi1KaZuk9y5n1lnFqW1oVj69q2tsAAem1fHcACMIFgZFpXuPcy0MihAAMRLDewo2PjAaVVBlU0kP0ABu1VYqUNlVAt7hNXhappLhfC7N8PD9JUcGXIK1z3JIHZYXpnqdVmlwXRZAmOTMcwqE6yZDZsI0NpD0Mk5NWDwyASPhHcs15Tu7iIC91xwn41xBqQiBbTta2YYMECVJ8mBrfteQyEdza0PT6R3L1zMDddlRlswlUuRz3SyjoqjVg9+wwGcOL3O2YZlBcuPId1q4+AyYDiPcOHYibTwHCWtvWoSkO8ywQA)

Answer (score 0):

The default function you provided for `transformResponse` return `Promise<Response>` instead of `Promise<ResponseType>`

You probably can juste cast response and add a default type to ReponseType = Response

```
const useFetch = <ResponseType = Response>(
  fetchInputFactory: () => RequestInfo | URL | [RequestInfo | URL, RequestInit],
  deps: DependencyList | undefined,
  transformResponse: (response: Response) => Promise<ResponseType> = async (response) => response as ResponseType
):
  | { loading: true }
  | { loading: false; success: true; response: ResponseType }
  | { loading: false; success: false; error: Error }
```

which from what I guess better describe the default behavior